# iPhone 4 gyroscope simulation

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, ios4

Is there any way to simulate `CMMotionManager`'s gyroscope output in the iPhone 4 simulator? `CMMotionManager`'s `gyroAvailable` seems to indicate that the simulator itself won't do it (which is understandable, given that it doesn't simulate acceleration data either), but I figured someone may have written a simple simulator drop-in for testing a project.

The new phones are in short supply in my city so far and it would be nice to give things a reasonable workout in the meantime!

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty old post, but may give you a starting point:

http://ifiddling.blogspot.com/2009/01/dummy2.html

Comment: This is cool, in that it leverages the existence of some other real accelerometers for the testing. Unfortunately, macbook's don't have gyroscopes! I ended up hacking a bit of a test up around the framework, but I will try and replicate the 'drop into the project' part of this acceleration example and make it generate random data for the gyroscope instead. Thanks!

Comment: @scott Your Macbook could have a gyro (disguised as "Sudden Motion Sensor"), i know mine does. Check out http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/device/orientation/deviceorientationsample.html in Google Chrome